# Inserting random values into column

Tags: sql-server

How can we insert random values into a newly created column in a table in SQL Server?

I tried this:

```
alter table [dbo].[employee] add phoneno int

select * from [dbo].[employee]
update employee set phoneno=(ROUND((RAND(),0)) where phoneno NULL
```

Comment: Why do you want to insert random values instead of a placeholder for unknown, such as NULL or 0? Also, with the code you tried, what was the outcome, did it error?

Comment: [How do I generate random number for each row in a TSQL Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than two steps you could define the initial values using a DEFAULT constraint on the new column.